# Clarification of pam rule with `success=3`

Tags: pam

I'm trying to configure `pam_ssh_agent_auth.so` to provide some users a password-less experience using sudo, when authenticating via ssh pubkey.

I started looking at the [gentoo wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Pam_ssh_agent_auth), which suggests to use

```
...
auth [success=3 default=ignore] pam_ssh_agent_auth.so file=/etc/ssh/sudo_authorized_keys
auth    include     system-auth                 <- 1st skipped
account include     system-auth                 <- 2nd skippedm
session include     system-auth                 <- 3rd skipped
...                                             <- should continue from here
```

I'm on a fedora and the `/etc/pam.d/sudo` looks like the following:

```
auth     [success=3 default=ignore] pam_ssh_agent_auth.so file=/etc/ssh/sudo_authorized_keys
auth     include     system-auth
account  include     system-auth
password include     system-auth
session  optional    pam_keyinit.so revoke
session  required    pam_limits.so
session  include     system-auth
```

I'm no PAM guru, but looking at man pages, I interpret `success=3` as "skip the next 3 rows if this rule succeeds", so I'd expect no password being asked if user correctly logs in and agent is present.

Alas, this is not working: the password is being asked anyway.

Authentication works as expected if, instead of using `[success=3 default=ignore]`, I just use `sufficient` - which I believe is basically the same, I cannot tell any difference in this case, since the stack of modules is composed by the next 3 modules.

Obviously, using `[success=3 default=ignore]` and `sufficient` are not the same thing, as I'm not getting the same result.

Can someone explain to me what are the actual differences and why the former is not working in this case?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, an `include` line is not a PAM module. Instead of counting the

```
auth     include     system-auth
```

as one item to skip, the PAM libraries will replace this `auth include` line with  all the `auth`-type lines from `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`. So to figure out which 3 lines are skipped by the `[success=3 default=ignore]`, you will need to replace the `include` statement with the appropriate contents of the `system-auth` file first first, and count the lines to skip after that.

Second, I don't think `[success=3 default=ignore]` will work across module types.

When authenticating the user, the application will first call `pam_authenticate()`, during which the PAM libraries will only process entries of the `auth` type. Once the user has been successfully authenticated, the application can call `pam_acct_mgmt()`, which will only process entries of the `account` type. And once that is completed, `pam_open_session()` will process the entries of the `session` type only.

As the authentication pass, account management pass and the session setup pass are three different operations, I think the `auth [success=3 default=ignore]` will only skip the next 3 lines **of type `auth` only**. And in your case, the lines that will be skipped will be within the `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` file.

---

When you use `auth sufficient`, it means the processing of the `auth` lines stops immediately if the module listed on the `auth sufficient` line reports a successful authentication. This means all `auth` lines in the `system-auth` file will be skipped, no matter how many of them there are.

When you use `auth [success=3 default=ignore]`, and among the next `auth` lines is an `include` line, you must also investigate the included file to have an accurate understanding of what will happen. The fact that password is still asked when you do this indicates there clearly is more than 3 `auth` lines in your `system-auth` file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I agree with you that `auth [success=3...` will skip the next 3 only for `auth` type, this is my understanding from the man page. What I missed, and you made very clear, is that `include` lines are not a PAM module and I have to look into the included files.

Answer (score 0):

From the man pages:

```
      sufficient
           if such a module succeeds and no prior required module has failed the PAM
           framework returns success to the application or to the superior PAM stack
           immediately without calling any further modules in the stack. A failure of a
           sufficient module is ignored and processing of the PAM module stack
           continues unaffected.
```

In your case, once it checks the "authorized key" file, it immediately returns success.

In the fedora example, if it successfully checks the "authorized key" file, it skips the next two steps and performs some session checks, e.g. pam_limits.so sets limits on how much resources the sudo user can use.